# Simple Login Program, Not sure how to return to main menu.

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to be able to return to the menu after creating a user. Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to programming so if you need additional information let me know.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1) Creating a Login");
        System.out.println("2) Login");
        System.out.println("9) Quit");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
        System.out.println(" ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuOption = sc.nextInt();
        while (menuOption != 9) {
            if (menuOption == 1) {

                System.out.println("Creating Username, please enter a string:");
                String user = sc.nextLine();
                user = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Creating Password, please enter a string:");
                String pass = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("user is" + user);
                System.out.println("pass is" + pass);

                if (menuOption == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your Username");
                    String inpUser = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Now please enter your Password");
                    String inpPass = sc.nextLine();

                    if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
                        System.out.print("Credentials Accepted");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Credentials Declined Please try again.");
                    }
                }


                if (menuOption == 9) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need some block of code to be repeated, put it inside of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the menu into your while loop so that it gets printed each time you re-loop through.

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menuOption = 0;
    while (menuOption != 9) {

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1) Creating a Login");
        System.out.println("2) Login");
        System.out.println("9) Quit");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
        System.out.println(" ");

        menuOption = sc.nextInt();

        switch(menuOption){
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("Creating Username, please enter a string:");
                String user = sc.nextLine();
                user = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Creating Password, please enter a string:");
                String pass = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("user is" + user);
                System.out.println("pass is" + pass);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                System.out.println("Please enter your Username");
                String inpUser = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Now please enter your Password");
                String inpPass = sc.nextLine();
                if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
                    System.out.print("Credentials Accepted");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Credentials Declined Please try again.");
                }
                break;
            }
            case 9: {
              break;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This way only menu option 1 is working.

Comment: I may have missed a bracket in the editor when making my post. I also would recommend moving your code into a switch. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @DanGreen I have updated my answer, with  a switch and its a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a new function:

```
private static int menu (final Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1) Creating a Login");
        System.out.println("2) Login");
        System.out.println("9) Quit");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        return sc.nextInt();
}
```

and then change your `main` function implementation to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuOption = menu(sc);
        while (menuOption != 9) {
            if (menuOption == 1) {

                System.out.println("Creating Username, please enter a string:");
                String user = sc.nextLine();
                user = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Creating Password, please enter a string:");
                String pass = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("user is" + user);
                System.out.println("pass is" + pass);
                menuOption = menu(sc); // everytime option 1 is selected, menu will be shown.

                if (menuOption == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your Username");
                    String inpUser = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Now please enter your Password");
                    String inpPass = sc.nextLine();

                    if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
                        System.out.print("Credentials Accepted");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Credentials Declined Please try again.");
                    }
                }


                if (menuOption == 9) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```